# Design Pattern: Lazy Singleton, Generics and Inheritance: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, singleton, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to implement Lazy Singleton with Generics and Inheritance. I have created a `abstract` super-class and declared a Map which will store all the instances of the child class of this class.

Here it is:

```
public abstract class AbstractXMLParser<T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static final Map<Class<? extends AbstractXMLParser>, AbstractXMLParser> INSTANCES = new HashMap<>();

    public AbstractXMLParser() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot instantiate");
    }

    private static class SingletonHolder<T> {       
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked"})
        private static <T> T getInstance() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
            Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) SingletonHolder.class.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            return clazz.newInstance();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static <T extends AbstractXMLParser> T getInstance() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) AbstractXMLParser.class.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        if(INSTANCES.containsKey(clazz)) {
            return (T) INSTANCES.get(clazz);
        } else {
            T instance = SingletonHolder.getInstance();
            INSTANCES.put(clazz, instance);
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

And one of the child class is:

```
public class ActivityTypeXMLParser extends AbstractXMLParser<ActivityTypeXMLParser>{
    private ActivityTypesXMLModel activityTypes;

    private ActivityTypeXMLParser() {

    }

    public static void main(String... strings) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        ActivityTypeXMLParser.getInstance();

    }
}
```

The `main` method is for testing purpose. But I am getting exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at com.edfx.adb.xml.parser.AbstractXMLParser.getInstance(AbstractXMLParser.java:25)
    at com.edfx.adb.xml.parser.ActivityTypeXMLParser.main(ActivityTypeXMLParser.java:30)
```

Now after debugging I found that

```
Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) AbstractXMLParser.class.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

is the reason for the exception, because `AbstractXMLParser.class.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` is returning `class java.lang.Object`. I need to get the `Class<T>` here. How can I extract it in the class `AbstractXMLParser` and in `SingletonHolder` of `AbstractXMLParser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this code:

- `static` methods are not inherited. `AbstractXMLParser.getInstance()` doesn't know that it's invoked in context of `ActivityTypeXMLParser` when called as `ActivityTypeXMLParser.getInstance()`.
- `AbstractXMLParser.class.getClass()` returns `Class' of`Class`, not`Class` of your class.
- It's not clear why do you need `AbstractXMLParser<T>` to be generic at all. Note that `T`s in `AbstractXMLParser`, `SingletonHolder` and `getInstance()` are different type parameters.

You need to pass the class in question to `getInstance()` implicitly:

```
getInstance(ActivityTypeXMLParser.class);
```

.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static <T extends AbstractXMLParser> T getInstance(Class<T> clazz) 
    throws InstantiationException, 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But now I am getting another error  java.lang.IllegalAccessException for clazz.newInstance(). Because the ActivityTypeXMLParser has private constructor. How can I overcome this?

Comment: If you really need to access `private` constructor using reflection, use `setAccessible(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution that I have made, would be helpful for someone.

The `abstract super-class`:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"all"})
public abstract class AbstractXMLParser<T> {    
    private static final Map<Class<? extends AbstractXMLParser>, AbstractXMLParser> INSTANCES = new HashMap<>();

    public AbstractXMLParser() {

    }

    private static class SingletonHolder<T> {               
        private static <T> T getInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
            Constructor<T> constructor = (Constructor<T>) clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
            constructor.setAccessible(true);            
            return constructor.newInstance(null);
        }
    }

    protected static <T extends AbstractXMLParser<T>> T getInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {      
        if(INSTANCES.containsKey(clazz)) {
            return (T) INSTANCES.get(clazz);
        } else {
            T instance = SingletonHolder.getInstance(clazz);
            INSTANCES.put(clazz, instance);
            return instance;
        }
    }

    protected static <T extends AbstractXMLParser<T>> void putInstance(Class<T> clazz, T instance) {
        if(!INSTANCES.containsKey(clazz)) {
            INSTANCES.put(clazz, instance);
        }
    }
}
```

And one of the child class:

```
public class ActivityTypeXMLParser extends AbstractXMLParser<ActivityTypeXMLParser>{

    private ActivityTypeXMLParser() {

    }   

    public static ActivityTypeXMLParser getInstance() {
        ActivityTypeXMLParser activityTypeXMLParser = null;

        try {
            activityTypeXMLParser = getInstance(ActivityTypeXMLParser.class);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }

        if(activityTypeXMLParser == null) {
            activityTypeXMLParser = new ActivityTypeXMLParser();
            putInstance(ActivityTypeXMLParser.class, activityTypeXMLParser);
        }

        return activityTypeXMLParser;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to get the generic type of the class which is a sub class of the abstract class.  However you are getting

```
AbstractXMLParser.class.getClass()
```

This is class of the abstract class which is always `Class`  Instead you should use just `getClass()` to the the class of the concrete class.